# Java, Generating a unique serial number using Maps/Collections

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I currently have a class that is responsible for generating a unique serial number provided the arguments 'full name' and 'Year'.

```
public static CustomerNumber getInstance(CustomerName name, Date dateIssued) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(dateIssued);
    int yearIssued = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    return name.getFirstName().charAt(0) + name.getLastName().charAt(0) + "-" + yearIssued + "-" + serialNumber;
}
```

The intended result is something like:

'John Smith', 2018 --> JS-2018-01,

'Joe Scott', 2018 --> JS-2018-02,

'Jaden Scott', 2018 --> JS-2018-03

'Maggie Scott', 2018 --> MS-2018-01,

Basically, if the prefix (Initials and Year) already exists, a serial number increment has to be applied to signify it's a new person.

I tried applying some sort of Map but I'm new to java/ programming and would like some advice

Comment: Why would you use a Map? (not saying it's wrong, just trying to follow your line of thinking)

Comment: @AleZalazar Honestly, it was kind of a hit and hope. maybe have the prefix as a key and the value as the number on the end. if the prefix exists, return the value and increment it by one and set it as the new value? If that's even possible :/

Comment: Absolutely yes, you can use `Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();` and put/get your stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use a `HashMap<String, Integer>`. The map would store the last value used as the `serialNumber`. Every time you compute the ID of a new customer, use `merge` to increment the hash map's value.

```
private static Map<String, Integer> serialNumbersMap = new HashMap<>();

public static CustomerNumber getInstance(CustomerName name, LocalDate dateIssued) {
    // I recommend you use java.time.LocalDate here
    int yearIssued = dateIssued.getYear();

    String key = name.getFirstName().charAt(0) + name.getLastName().charAt(0) + "-" + yearIssued;

    int serialNumber = serialNumbersMap.merge(key, 1, Integer::sum);
    String id = key + (serialNumber < 10? "-0": "-") + serialNumber;
    return id;
}
```

If `getInstance` can be called multiple times with the same customer name and date, and you want to return the same ID if that happens, you need another map to store known customer IDs.

```
private static Map<String, String> knownIDsMap = new HashMap<>();
```

First check in this map if you have seen the customer name before. If you haven't, do the above, otherwise return the value in the map.

```
public static CustomerNumber getInstance(CustomerName name, LocalDate dateIssued) {
    int yearIssued = dateIssued.getYear();

    String knownIDKey = name.getFirstName() + name.getLastName() + yearIssued;

    String knownID = knownIDsMap.get(knownIDKey);

    if (knownID != null) {
        return knownID;
    }

    // same as above...

    knownIdsMap.put(knownIDKey, id);
    return id;
}
```

For a better implementation, create a class `CustomerIDInfo` that encapsulates a `CustomerName` and `LocalDate`, override `equals` and `hashcode`. Then you can make your map of type `HashMap<CustomerIDInfo, String>`, without having to do all these string manipulations.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your help! I just couldn't work out this line however.

serialNumbersMap.compute(key, (k, v) => v == null ? 1 : v + 1);

Comment: @rabin-bhandari That line basically says. Get the value of `serialNumbersMap.get(key)`. If it is null, `serialNumbersMap.put(key, 1)`, otherwise, `serialNumbersMap.put(key, serialNumbersMap.get(key) + 1)`. And `compute` returns the new value associated with `key`. As you can see, all that logic can be written succinctly with `compute`.

Answer (score 0):

so, you just wanted to cache your generated serial number and increment it if it's duplicate right? If so, all you need is "Set", and you can do while loop to increment it until it's unique.

```
String baseValue = name.getFirstName().charAt(0) + name.getLastName().charAt(0) + "-" + yearIssued + "-";
String value = baseValue + serialNumber;
while(set.contains(value)){
    value = baseValue + (serialNumber++);
}
set.add(value);
return value;
```